# Better to add CSS timed transition to link selector (a) or to the hover state (a:hover)?

Tags: css, css-transitions

When using the CSS transitions for creating rollovers that fade in/out, is it better to place it under the `a` selector or the `a:hover` selector?

My instinct is to place it on the `a:hover` selector because that’s the active portion of the rollover but looking at examples, people seem to declare them after the `a` instead.

Both seem to work perfectly but I’d really like to know which is considered “correct”, and if possible, why.

So, this:

```
a { color:blue; transition:.5s; }

a:hover { color:red; }
```

Or this (*my instinct*):

```
a { color:blue; }

a:hover { color:red; transition:.5s; }
```

Thanks.

(*Vendor prefixes intentionally omitted*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your needs, using the `transition` property below in `a`

```
a { color:blue; transition:.5s; }
```

Will transit the element when you mouseover/hover the element, as well as when you mouseout

Where this

```
a:hover { color:red; transition:.5s; }
```

Will transit the element only on hover, it will get back to normal the moment you take out the mouse.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4R8zP/) (Too and fro transition)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/4R8zP/1/) (Will transit only on `hover` and will be back to normal once the mouse is off the element)

> Note: I've increased the `transition` time to show how it actually
>   matters.

---

Conclusion: Generally speaking, `transition` shouldn't be used on `:hover` as it won't transit when the mouse is taken out of the element. But as I said again, it depends on the needs.